# Cannot serialize navigation properties correctly while performing Web API Patch operation from Kendo Grid

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'm currently using Web API v2 with OData v3 linked up to a Kendo Grid.  I'm having problems getting the grid to serialize a model correctly to the [`PatchEntityAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj918203(v=vs.118).aspx) on the [`AsyncEntitySetController<TEntity, TKey>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890498(v=vs.118).aspx).  The `Delta<TEntity>` that is passed to the `PatchEntityAsync` method is `null` which obviously is not correct.

First, the Entity Framework models.  I have a `GameSeries` definition:

```
[Table("stats.GameSeries")]
public class GameSeries
{
    [Key]
    public int GameSeriesId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

And then there is the `Game` definition, each `Game` instance has a reference to a `GameSeries` instance:

```
[Table("stats.Game")]
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int GameSeriesId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GameSeriesId")]
    public virtual GameSeries GameSeries { get; set; }

    public int Revision { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

When querying for a `Game` using JSON, and issuing an `$expand` on the `GameSeries` property, I get the following, which is expected/correct:

```
{
    "odata.metadata":
        "http://localhost:7566/odata/$metadata#Games",
    "odata.count":"58",
    "value":[
    {
        "GameSeries": {
            "GameSeriesId": 1,
            "Description":"Street Fighter IV",
            "Notes":null
        },
        "GameId": 1,
        "Description": "Street Fighter IV",
        "GameSeriesId": 1,
        "Revision": 1,
        "Tag": null,
        "Notes": null
    }, {
        "GameSeries": {
            "GameSeriesId":1,
            "Description": "Street Fighter IV",
            "Notes": null
        },
        "GameId": 2,
        "Description": "Super Street Fighter IV",
        "GameSeriesId": 1,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Tag": null,
        "Notes": null
    },
    // And so on...
  ]
}
```

I'm exposing these through an OData Web API (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.2.0) endpoint to a Kendo UI Grid.  Here's the configuration for the grid:

```
function initializeGrid(selector, entitySet, key, modelFields, columns, expand) {
    // Edit and destroy commands.
    columns.push({ command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operations" });

    // The main key is not editable.
    modelFields[key].editable = false;
    modelFields[key].defaultValue = 0;

    var baseODataUrl = "/odata/" + entitySet,
        options = {
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                pageSize: 50,
                //autoSync: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: baseODataUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            $expand: expand
                        }
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: function(data) {
                            return baseODataUrl + "(" + data[key] + ")";
                        },
                        type: "patch",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: function (data) {
                            return baseODataUrl + "(" + data[key] + ")";
                        },
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: baseODataUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                },
                batch: false,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                schema: {
                    data: function (data) {
                        return data.value;
                    },
                    total: function (data) {
                        return data["odata.count"];
                    },
                    model: {
                        id: key,
                        fields: modelFields
                    }
                }
            },
            height: 550,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            editable: "popup",
            navigatable: true,
            columns: columns
        };

    selector.kendoGrid(options);
}

$(function () {
    var baseODataUrl = "/odata/",
        gameSeriesIdDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.value;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data["odata.count"];
                }
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: baseODataUrl + "GameSeries",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        }),
        gameSeriesIdAutoCompleteEditor = function(container, options) {
            $('<input data-text-field="Description" data-value-field="GameSeriesId" data-bind="value:GameSeriesId"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataSource: gameSeriesIdDataSource,
                    dataTextField: "Description",
                    dataValueField: "GameSeriesId"
                });
        };

    initializeGrid($("#grid"), "Games", "GameId", {
        GameId: {
            title: "Game ID",
            editable: false
        },
        Description: { type: "string" },
        GameSeriesId: { type: "integer" },
        Revision: { type: "integer" },
        Tag: { type: "string" },
        Notes: { type: "string" }
    }, [
        { field: "GameId", title: "Game ID" },
        "Description",
        { field: "GameSeries.Description", title: "Game Series", editor: gameSeriesIdAutoCompleteEditor },
        "Revision",
        "Tag",
        "Notes"
    ], "GameSeries");
});
}(jQuery));
```

This will render the grid correctly, where I'll get `GameSeries.Description` displayed instead of the numeric ID of the `GameSeries`.

However, I believe part of the problem comes from how I define the custom editor, specifically the `data` attributes that Kendo requires:

```
$('<input data-text-field="Description" data-value-field="GameSeriesId" data-bind="value:GameSeriesId"/>')
```

I get the feeling I should use dot notation to reference the `GameSeries` property on the `Game` instance, but I'm not sure how.

Additionally, I believe the binding here is contributing to the create command failing.  There should be some way to set the data binding attributes which will allow for new creations, as well as editing existing ones.

However, when I get the editor to pop up for an existing instance, it does so correctly with the drop down list populated with all of the `GameSeries` instances.

I can make changes, and when I do, I notice through Fiddler that the body is being passed through, although I notice some discrepancies:

```
{
    "GameSeries": {
        "GameSeriesId": 1,
        "Description": "Street Fighter IV",
        "Notes": null
    },
    "GameId": "1",
    "Description":
    "Street Fighter IV",
    "GameSeriesId": "4",
    "Revision": "1",
    "Tag": "Test",
    "Notes": null
}
```

In this case, the `GameSeriesId` property is populated correctly with the change (I *want* 4) but the expanded `GameSeries` property has a "GameSeriesId" of 1.

When this call is made, the `Delta<Game>` instance passed in is null.

What I've tried:

I've noticed that the `GameSeriesId` property on the expanded `GameSeries` property isn't stringified.  I've changed the value to `"1"`" and the `Delta<Game>` instance is still null.

I've replicated the call to the OData point to not include the extended `GameSeries` property, so the payload looks like this:

```
{
    "GameId": "1",
    "Description":
    "Street Fighter IV",
    "GameSeriesId": "4",
    "Revision": "1",
    "Tag": "Test",
    "Notes": null
}
```

And the `Delta<Game>` is populated.  I'm not sure if getting the expanded `GameSeries` property droped from the payload is the right approach, or whether or not it should be tackled on the server side, or in the Kendo grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the foreign key id is changed successfully you can just exclude the navigation property `GameSeries` when doing the update.

EF works so well when updating the relationship just by using the foreign key id.

So let the OData point to include the `GameSeries`, but exclude it when doing update. You can use [**parameterMap**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) to intercept the update operation.

```
parameterMap: function (data, type) {
    if (type === "update") {
        delete data.GameSeries;
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    // Returns as it is.
    return data;
}
```

**update**

To sync the editor with the grid, you need to bind the change event and change the property of the model in the grid manually.

```
gameSeriesIdAutoCompleteEditor = function (container, options) {
    /* omitted code */
    .kendoDropDownList({
        /* omitted code */
        change: function (e) {
            options.model.GameSeries = this.dataItem();
        }
```

Comment: This allows the database edit to go through.  However, the grid doesn't update at all, it still points to the original item referenced by the foreign key, even after the patch is applied on the server.  How can I keep the UI in sync with the database change that was just applied?

Comment: @casperOne, I'm not sure whether kendo actually uses the data that is sent back from the server, to actually refresh the grid you can attach to `complete` event and call `$(selector).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();`, but unfortunately that will refresh the whole grid, and kendo currently doesn't support refresh per row, so I think you can just change the grid based on selected option for the least database roundtrip